# debug a .so file build in the other host in Android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I build a android apk which contains c++ code in a linux machine .
so how can i debug it with android studio in a mac machine?

when I add the breakpoint to the android studio. the AS shows
"Breakpoint will not currently be hit, No executable code is associated with the file"

Comment: That message means that the line you try to set break-point at (or likely more), is not getting ever compiled, or you are trying to debug a **`release`** build (which has probably `ProGuard` enabled). In other words, AS does not lie.

Comment: BTW, what does your "`other machine`" title mean? You can not debug and `.so` file without `debug-symbols` (I mean, specific files which depends on compiler you used). So, you would need to have the `debug-symbols` on any machine you debug (they are normally generated when compiling, but just mentioning cause your title).

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
Actually, I have two computers, and I want to debug the so file compiled on the host B on the host A. there are source code on the host A and B

Comment: Try recompiling with `Clang` to generate debug-symbols, or research about how to transfer your debug-symbols (but first ensure that your library is NOT built for release).

Comment: yes , the build type is debug,  it is seems that i need to config the paths  mapping?